# How to return match element ID using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to return matched element ID using jquery filter method but it is returning 'object object' [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTF8f/10/)

//css

```
.none{display:none}
```

//html

```
<div class="none">
 <span style="display:none">first</span>
 <span style="display:block">second</span>
</div>
```

//script

```
visibles = $('.none').find('span').filter(function(){
if($(this).css('display') == 'block')   
return $(this).attr('id');
});
alert(visibles);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback you give to filter returns a value used to filter.

If you have only one match, use this :

```
visibleId = $('.none').find('span').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('display') == 'block'
}).attr('id');
```

If you want to get an array of the match ids, use

```
visibles = $('.none').find('span').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('display') == 'block'
}).map(function(){ return this.id }).get();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/EM89W/)

Comment: there is any other way to do that

Comment: nice example, can you please tell me why you use .get() here

Comment: Without `get`, you have an object that looks like an array but isn't really an array.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) returns matched elements, so you need to get the `id` value after filtering the elements.

```
visibles = $('.none').find('span').filter(function(){
   if($(this).css('display') == 'block')   
       return true;
}).attr('id');
alert(visibles);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xTF8f/12/)